# Indexing 10 million documents using Elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elastica

I'm trying to index 10 million documents into my Elasticsearch index using the Elastica API.
I'm running my script over an Ubuntu server with 16G RAM and 8 cores.

So far, I can't index more than 250000 docs. My script is breaking and returning an unknown error.

***Can someone describe me the step to insure the indexing of this amount of data?***

I have found a question similar to mine [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22762908/indexing-speed-of-elasticsearch-for-10-million-events), but the answers don't seem very clear to me.

**EDIT :**

I have ran the index script that [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1218285/nate) suggested from [here](http://blog.smeef.co.uk/elasticsearch-swap-index-type-application-job/) and I got the following output :

```
close index
{
 "acknowledged" : true
}
refresh rate
{
 "acknowledged" : true
}
merge policy
{
 "acknowledged" : true
}
replicas
{
 "acknowledged" : true
}
flush
{
 "acknowledged" : true
}
buffer
{
 "acknowledged" : true
}
{
 "acknowledged" : true
}
```

***PS:*** I slightly modified the script for more visibility on the output

**EDIT 2:**
I have switched from Elastica to using the [elasticsearch-jdbc-river](https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-river-jdbc) and now it indexing around 5 millions but still not the whole database.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/eliasah/11288834) is the json file for the river and the script file for put it on Elasticsearch is [here.](https://gist.github.com/eliasah/11288893)

Comment: The question your reference is more performance based, you seem to be encountering an exception. Ensure logging is enables and capture the stack trace leading up to the error.

Comment: How can I do that? I'm struggling actually with both performance and this exception

Comment: Run the scripts mentioned in this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/22763203/1218285

Comment: As for the logs, go to your installation and find logs directory. Find the appropriate log for the date you require, [ClusterName].log.[Date] is the format you should look for. Update you question with the stack trace around the time

Comment: The update wont help anyone solve your problem as to why you can only index a certain amount of documents this is just acknowledgements from Elasticsearch regarding operations you are carrying out. Please find the logs I noted above and update your question with that.

Comment: Can you include this in your answer?

Comment: I configured the DEBUG mode in `logging.yml` and the `path.log` so I can get my log data but it's not writing anything in it. I'm trying as well to see what is happening with the elasticsearch search `console` mode and still nothing. I can't even see what it is indexing.

Comment: I also added some exception log from the script I am running and I got the following : `Indexer/vendor/ruflin/elastica/lib/Elastica/Transport/Http.php : Operation timed out`

Comment: links are broken

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this issue a long time ago, but I have forgotten to write an answer.

I have considered the second solution applying the elasticsearch-jdbc-river which is deprecated as from now when I am writing the answer.

Nevertheless, the problem with the river back then was with considering the default query_timeout option that seems not to be enough by default considering the heave SQL query I was using. The option killed the process after the query_timeout elapsed.

I have increased the query_timeout value and it solved my problem.